# How do I convert Linux C++ source code into Windows C++ source code?

Tags: c++

I have one application wrote for linux in c++ and now I want to use same c++ source code in windows.

How do I convert it into windows c++ source code so that it will run on windows platform ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux C++ source code"?

Answer (score 5):

If it is actual correct and standard C++ code, then it will run on any platform without modification. If it isn't, well... You didn't provide enough detail to answer the question.

Comment: What if it is correct and standard C++ code that uses some Linux-specific libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Converting software is a big thing if you didn't write it with portability in mind.

Obviously the first step would be to get a c++ compiler of choice for windows (vc++) and try to compile.

If you heavily rely on network/ the filesystem/ threads consider the use of a portable libary like [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html), [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), ...

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to write an **Platform Abstraction Layer** for all platform/OS related api calls, this layer shall expose a common interface for all platform dependant api types.

It basically shall act as an Abstraction between your Application and the OS/platform.

For each port(Linux or Windows) you implement this interface. You can provide the abstraction as an separate library for each port which ensures that your calling application remains the same only the library to be linked changes.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful on how it is done due to potential dependencies on the system libraries, for example, sockets under Linux, is different to the Windows Sockets (Sure there is a similarly named functions).

It might help you to use the macros such as this

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
... functions targetting the Windows platform
#else // __GNU_LINUX__
... functions targetting the Linux platform
#endif
```

This is an example mechanism of doing it, in that way, you can differentiate and handle the platform specifics... so just beware of the subtle differences in the platforms...

That is unless, you are using cross-platform compatible libraries such as QT/wxWidgets or similar, but do not assume that the code will work as is regardless of platform.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a simple "console" application using simple C++ , then you should be able to use the code directly on Windows.

You can either use gxx/g++ on windows and rebuild with the same make file; or use Visual Studio Express and import the source code in the project and buid it (there might/will be issues so just fix the compilation errors/warnings).

If the Linux code use API and SDK  (UI?) not available on Windows, then you will have to port the code to work on windows by using the native Win32 or MFC or some other type library that your application use.

M.